# Jquery resizing max width of an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to resize the max width of an element on click and it won't take in the initial value before resizing (which is super annoying). Here's the css:

```
.content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 17.2rem;
    max-width: calc(100% - 19.2rem);
    width: calc(100% - 19.2rem);
    margin: 1rem 1rem 0px 1rem;
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$('.content').animate({
    'width': '+=15rem',
    'max-width': '+=15rem', 
    'margin-left': '-=15rem'
}, "slow" );
```

Essentially without the max width the .content box overflows horizontally which is really bad, but with the max width it won't resize the content box when the object to the left minimizes.

What is really annoying is that the width will add 15rem onto the calculated width in the css while the max-width will simply make the max width 15rem and not take the initial value from the css (that's the heart of the problem I think)

Comment: So how do I get this to work?

Comment: You'd have to look into getting `max-width` from [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `.css() doesn't take class styles into account` What? [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) returns computed style

Comment: @A.Wolff I meant things that appear in a stylesheet but aren't necessarily related to the current state of the element, like `max-width` for example.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But it is, `max-width` is computed. But it returns its computed value  http://jsfiddle.net/3d8m1jn0/

Comment: @A.Wolff you are correct, my apologies. Quick test shows that jQuery displays the string `calc(-307.2px + 100%)` for `$('.content').css('max-width')`.

Comment: Why do you animate both `max-width` and `width`? Is it what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/fmm1196h/ ?

Comment: That's said, i have no idea why it doesn't work specifically for `max-*` properties?!

Comment: Because for some reason the text in my project overflows without the max-width. its posted here: http://rheisen.meteor.com

Comment: @Rheisen Just checked your website, you have fixed it, right?!

Comment: No, it should be able to fit more of those boxes when the tab is hidden. The width (I believe) is fixed by the initial max width.

Comment: @Rheisen Sorry, i don't see any issue on chrome. Not sure what is your expected behaviour, seems correct layout for me

Comment: Wait... somehow I've managed to fix it... I have no clue how.

Comment: @Rheisen Your previous width was overwritten by other rule but don't remember which one (inline style maybe?!)

Comment: @A.Wolff Honestly I'm not even sure... the state of web design is beyond me right now I haven't slept in almost 26 hours lol

Comment: @Rheisen So have a good night.. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff It's still broken... resizing the screen breaks it... oh well.